# What is this piece of code in Matlab doing

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

This is a snippet from a program I am trying to understand. I have changed the variable names for easier understanding. I haven't done much coding in MatLab so I can't really understand what's happening. When I kept a=magic(4) and got the output from this code I thought it was sorting or something but it doesn't seem so with the other input

```
a = [14 41 4 16;7 12 45 0;12 12 45 17; 3 2 1 15]
b=a(:)
c=zeros(4,4)
```

a is a 4x4 matrix,
b is a column vector of a,
c is a 4X4 matrix of zeros.`

```
 for kk = 1:length(b)
    c(a==b(kk)) = kk;
end
```

c =

```
1    5    9   13
2    7   11   14
7    7   11   15
4    8   12   16
```

if I try a=magic(4), where
a =

```
16    2    3   13
 5   11   10    8
 9    7    6   12
 4   14   15    1
```

then 
c =

```
1    5    9   13
2    6   10   14
3    7   11   15
4    8   12   16
```

Comment: `a` is shown as 4x3...

Comment: This code is pretty much pointless. It assigns the index of the last occurrence of each unique element of `a` to all the locations corresponding to that element into `c`.

Comment: ... which leads to "sorting" for arrays with all unique elements like obtained from `magic()`.

Comment: my bad with the 4x3 array

Comment: I just tried with a 4x4 matrix, and updated it, this code is being used in a program so it is not all pointless

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the comments is correct - perhaps it serves a function within the program, however out of context the code does seem pretty much pointless.

This is essentially what is happening. Suppose you have a matrix A

```
A = [3 4; 
     5 6]
```

Then B will look like this:

```
B = [3 4 5 6]
```

C is then created by comparing the kkth element of A to the kkth element of B. If the two are equal, then the kkth element of C will be kk.
Thus, in the example above, C will look like this:

```
C = [1 2; 
     3 4]
```

If, as you have found out, there are multiple entries of the same number in your original matrix A, then the final matrix C will only have the index of the last unique occurence of that number. So, if

```
A = [3 3; 
     5 6]

B = [3 3 5 6]

C = [2 2; 
     3 4]
```

The reason your first `C` has 7 three times is because the last position of 12 is at position 7. The reason your second `C` is different from your first `C` is because the `A` that it was made from is totally unique.